# how to increase the upload term limit of taxonomy csv module

Tags: drupal-6

**I am trying to upload the csv through taxonomy csv upload module but it gives an error of term character limit to 255 on uploading the terms with more characters.
Is there any way to increase this limit so that i could upload my terms.
thanks**

Answer (score 0):

The term name, by default, is limited to a total of 255 chars in the mySQL database.  There is nothing that can go beyond this, as far as I can see.  Since you cannot modify the database, there is no way to make this beyond 255 characters, without first making some major modifications to the database, which could, in turn, give you many issues.  If your terms are beyond 255 characters, the best bet is to restrict the names to less than 255.

For reference purposes, the taxonomy csv import module does limit the amount of characters you can upload by default.  The following file is where they are located: `taxonomy_csv/import/taxonomy_csv.import.parser.api.inc`.  Inside of this file, you will find the numbers on the following line numbers: 
`50, 142, 159, 196, 235, 279, 306, and 341`

As always, back up your database before changing any settings or structure.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but i am changing the data type of the column name in term_data table and its not allowing me to do that, so i increased the limit from 255 to 300(more than this it is not allowing), but didn't helped as i believe the limit is set into the code of csv upload module.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You will not be able to do it safely without major modifications.  You'll have to google how to modify the structure of keys.  Basically, you have to unlink the keys, then change the structure, then relink the keys.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more.  Good luck to you.